# Android for Visual Studio Professional 2013

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, visual-studio, smartphone

I want to develop some web pages in Android using Visual Studio. The version of VS is 2013 Professional running on Windows 10. What should I install to get Android on VS?

Many thanks!

Comment: Well I searched and what I found didn't work for me. For example I tried xamarin but it gave me error at install. So?

Comment: I'm confused here. If you want to develop web pages, you don't need Xamarin, and it won't matter whether you want the page to be opened in any OS with modern browser. Do you want to develop PlayStore apps, or a website that can be opened from an Android?

Comment: A website which can be opened from Android. It is kind of a industrial app. I mean that web pages I build I want to be seen fine on a smartphone. And I thought to make it directly on Android.

Answer (score 1):

Use google chrome emulation https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode or configure remote debugging if you need real device test: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, but I need to develop my app in VS.

Comment: You'll develop your app in visual studio and then debug it in google chrome.

Comment: And to develop it, don't I need Android plugin for VS?

Comment: As I see in your question you are developing website on ASP.NET, if not you need cordova.

Comment: Cordova https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42675. Android SDK https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other

Comment: Exactly, I'm gonna use ASP.NET. So I need to install Android Studio? If yes can I link vs project with android studio? Or how? Sorry for so many questions but I'm new in this domain. Many thanks!

Comment: You don't need android studio and android in VS. Use device emulation like I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Well thank you but don't know if I can develop the kind of app I must do it. It is kind of a industrial app. I mean that web pages I build I want to be seen fine on a smartphone. And I thought to make it directly on Android.

Comment: It seems there's a misunderstanding here. A smartphone browser is just like any other browser, you might need to account for specific capabilities, but otherwise it's just a browser. You can develop any site for any browser using any framework.The Chrome emulation mentioned in the answer will be the only thing you need. The developed site would also be perfectly fine when opened in iOS or WP. When you're using the remote debugging mentioned, your website will be opened on your actual android device directly, no Android Studio needed. Same goes for chrome emulation.

Comment: Ok. Many thanks for your reply!